# After using a formula in an .each, the number in the array won't change

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, ruby-1.8.7

What I have is:

```
p(array)
array.each { |c| c=c*y**z-1 ; z=z+1  }
p(array)
```

The array is:

```
[35, 35, 35]
```

`y` is 36, `z` is a counter, `c` is the value in the array.

Before the formula I get:

```
[35, 35, 35]

[formula happens]
```

After the formula:

```
[35, 35, 35]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To modify array itself use the [`#map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-map-21), instead of [`#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-each) method of `Array`. Because the `#each` method is used only for value enumerations for `Array`, or other classes that include `Enumerable` module. Therefore, do as follows:

```
array.map! { |c| c=c*y**z-1 ; z=z+1 ; c }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. If you wouldn't mind, could you tell me why this works as opposed to what I had?

Comment: Look at my answer, I had explained the reason :)

Answer (score 3):

The `each` method in the Array class does not mutate an existing instance. It just iterates over it. You should use `collect!` method instead.